# Triple dot product relation to norm, angle and basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

So I'm asked to take the dot triple product, defined this way:

$$\vec u \cdot \vec v \times \vec w   $$

And I know that: $||\vec u|| = 1 $, $||\vec v|| = 2 $, $||\vec w|| = 3 $, ($\vec u$, $\vec v$, $\vec w$) is a negative basis and that the vectors are orthogonal to each other.

By the geometric interpretation of the triple dot product (volume of the paralelepiped) I know that the volume is $1*2*3 = 6$ and because it's a negative basis, the answer is $-6$. But I didn't want to use the geometric interpretation. Instead, I wanted to use the determinant definition:

$$\vec u \cdot \vec v \times \vec w  = \begin{vmatrix}
u1 &u2 &u3\\
v1 &v2 &v3\\
w1 &w2 &w3
\end{vmatrix}$$

of course:

$$\vec u = (u1, u2, u3)$$
$$\vec v = (v1, v2, v3)$$
$$\vec w = (w1, w2, w3)$$
Is there a way to relate the determinant definition of the dot product with the norm of the vectors and the angles between each one (and also, the orientation of the basis)?

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one choice for $u,v$ and $w$. Then you can not solve using an explicity way. But using the relation $u\cdot v\times w=uvw\cos\theta\sin\phi$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v\times w$, and $\phi$  is the angle between $v$ and $w$.
You can get the result without use a geometry.

Comment: And what can we say about the basis orientation?